# Unstable 2.4ghz wifi speeds - LG G6

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, lg-g6

A few weeks ago I noticed a strange wifi problem with my Lg G6 when connected to a 2.4ghz router at home (wrt 320n).

Wifi speed is terribly unstable. Although wifi signal shows up as excellent, running speedtest I get 10mps download, and when retesting 30 sec later , speed is at 1mbps. (See screenshot attached). I tried different wifi channels, scanned channels with Wifi Alanalyzer app, but problem always appears.

This translates into unusable voip quality and intermittenly very slow loading of webpages.

Problem doesn't appear at 5Ghz , and other devices at home don't have this issue using the same 2.4ghz router.

I have to use my router at 2.4ghz mode for backwards compatibility with some older devices (Chromecast).

[image: wifi speed test problem lg g6]

Any clues?
Thanks